# URL Changes After Removing Child Component

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement dynamic add / remove child component in Angular.  My parent component keeps a list of the children and adds to the list or removes from it depending on what is selected by the user.

Add works fine, but when I go to remove a child, the URL changes and moves me off the page I'm on.  I would like to stay on the page and have the remove function remove the selected child component.  I noticed the URL is being changed to '#' and tries to route to that instead of updating the page and showing the result.

```
import { Component, ComponentRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
  children: any[] = [];
  constructor(public vrc: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addChild(){
    this.children.push({});
  }

  removeChild(index: number) {
    this.children.splice(index,1);
  }

  getRemovecallback(index : number) {
    return () => this.removeChild(index);
  }

}
```

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="PanelController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
    <h1 class="page-header">Dynamic Panels</h1>
    <hr>
    <section>
        <div class="" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addChild()">Add Panel</button>
        </div>

        <!-- This is where we will insert the dynamic components 
        <div #container style="display: inline-block;"></div> -->
        <panel-child *ngFor="let child of children;let i= index" [index]="i" [removeCallback]="getRemovecallback(i)"></panel-child>

    </section>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel-child',
  templateUrl: './panel-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-child.component.css']
})
export class PanelChildComponent {

  @Input()
  unique_key!: number;
  viewRef: any;
  parentRef!: PanelComponent;

  @Input() index: number = 0;
  @Input() removeCallback :Function = () => {};

  constructor(private parent: PanelComponent) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Obtain the parent component reference from the injected instance
    this.parentRef = this.parent;
  }

  remove() {
    this.removeCallback(this.index);
  }

}
```

```
<div class="" style="display: inline-block;width: 50%;">
    

    <div class="card" style="min-height: 400px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <h4 style="margin-left: 5px;">Dynamic Panel</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown col-md-1" dropdown>
                <a class="fas fa-ellipsis-h text-dark" dropdownToggle></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu mt-2 mr-3" *dropdownMenu>
                  <a class="dropdown-item"> Add Widget</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Notes</a>
                  <a (click)="remove()" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete Panel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
             
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="card-body" [style.background-color]="'white'">
            <p>Any block level element inside the app-grid--layout will show in a grid!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it happends bacause you are using `<a>` elements as buttons.

this element is meant to change the url. to prevent that you can replace `<a>` tag with somehing else, or add click handlers on them with calling `$event.preventDefault()` to prevent their default behavior - navigation

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you.